# Playing video with javafx webengine

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I have this in my .html page:

```
<div class="video_player" id="video_div">

        </div>
```

and I am loading the video content with javascript :

```
var vidFrame = document.getElementById("video_div");
    var vidHtml = '<video width="100%" id="player" onended="updateProgress()" height="500px"  controls="controls" id="player"><source id="video_src" src="' + studyController.getCurrentContent() + '"/></video>'
    vidFrame.innerHTML = vidFrame.innerHTML + vidHtml;
```

studyController is basically a javascrip interface object passed to the webengine. It reference this code:

```
public String getCurrentContent() {

        String code = superModel.getSuperStudyModel().get(module).get(lesson).getPathB64();
        try {
            String fileExe = superModel.getSuperStudyModel().get(module).get(lesson).getName();
            fileExe = fileExe.substring(fileExe.lastIndexOf("."));
            File file = PBUtils.writeByteArraysToFile(Base64.getDecoder().decode(code), fileExe);
            code = "file://" + file.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(code);
//            showMessage(code);
        } catch (IOException e) {
//            showMessage(e.getMessage());
        }

        return code;
    }
```

this works well and I had no problem with the implementation when building. But when I package the jar file, the video never plays. Is there something i had to do to make this work on a package version ?

Comment: Please refer  this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/28324289/4254056